# Intuition behind this Olympiad problem using generating functions

Tags: number-theory, contest-math, generating-functions, card-games

From here https://web.archive.org/web/20160418085410/https://db.math.ust.hk/notes_download/elementary/algebra/ae_A11.pdf

> Example 4.1. (CGMO 2004)
>
> A set of poker has $32$ cards. $30$ of them are
> in red, yellow and blue, with $10$ cards in each colour, given the
> numbers $1, 2, …, 10$ respectively. $2$ of them are different jokers, both
> with the number $0$. A card with the number $k$ counts for $2^k$ points. Call
> a group of cards a ‘good group’ if the sum of their points is $2004$.
> Calculate the number of ‘good groups’

They define:

$$G(x) = (1+x)^2(1+x^2)^3(1+x^4)^3...(1+x^{1024})^3$$

I cannot figure out how this was constructed exactly. What is the logic behind building this in this way?

Comment: Jokers have count $2^0 = 1$ point. Card $k$ has $2^k$ points. In any selection if you include card $k$, the  $2^k$ is added. Hence the term $1+x^{2^k}$ represents the selection of card $k$, one for each color. The jokers are represented by $1+x$ each and hence by $(1+x)(1+x)$. Thus you need the coefficient of 2004 in this product.

Comment: @Muralidharan, why each term is a cube?

Comment: One term for each color and $(1+x)^2$ for the joker cards.

Comment: Got it.  I forgot the color.  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each card numbered $k$, you can either put it in your group, which adds $2^k$ to your score, or leave it out of the group, which keeps your score the same. If we want the coefficient of $x^s$ to represent the number of ways to score exactly $s$, this means that we multiply by $(1 + x^{2^k})$. Why? Because that means either multiply by $1 = x^0$ OR multiply by $x^{2^k}$, which means either adding $0$ to the score OR adding $2^k$ to the score.

Then, it is just a matter of counting the number of cards of number $k$ and multiplying the relevant factor. We have two jokers numbered $0$, which gives two factors of $(1+x)$, and three of all other cards numbered $1$ to $10$ which gives three factors of each of $(1+x^2), (1+x^4), \ldots, (1 + x^{2^{10}})$.
The end result is the expression
$$G(x) = (1+x)^2(1+x^2)^3(1+x^4)^3...(1+x^{1024})^3$$

By construction, the coefficient of $x^s$ in this expression is the number of ways to get score $s$. So we want the coefficient of $x^{2014}$ in the above.